# Ubuntu's SFML 'no matching function for call to "sf:SocketUDP::Receive(sf::Packet&,sf::IPAddress&)" '

Tags: c++, networking, ubuntu, sfml

I was trying to compile my SFML networking test, when the (possibly)bug happened.

In SFML 1.6's reference, SocketUDP has the member function I'm trying to use.

However, in SFML 2.0's reference the function has changed, and now requires an extra field, unsigned short &remotePort.

It seems that the library would require me to use the v2.0 method, even though my version is 1.6.

I can reproduce the bug with

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::SocketUDP s;
    sf::Packet p;
    sf::IPAddress a;
    s.Receive(p,a);
    return 0;
}
```

So, is this a bug in Ubuntu's SFML or what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more inspection and downloading SFML from the website, it seems that the function has been changed.

They really should update their reference pages.